# AngularJS select options with id and array index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a drop down select box with options coming from an array and I want to have access to the some property of the selected option and the array index.

So, for example I have an array:

```
selectOptions = [{id: 1, name: 'name1'}, {id: 2, name: 'name2'}, {id: 3, name: 'name3'}];
```

and when one of the options is chosen I want to have access to the selected option's id and index position in selectOptions.
Right now I have this for selecting the id:

```
<select name="currentlySelected" ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in selectOptions" ng-change="change(selectedId)">
</select>
```

But I also want to send as an input to the change function the index of the selected option in the selectOptions array. I want to be able to do this:

```
$scope.change = function ($parentId, $arrayId) {
 $scope.currentlySelected = $scope.selectOptions[$arrayId];
 $scope.selectedId = $parentId;
};
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I give you *a* solution I want to first suggest that you dont do what you are trying to do.  You are basically keeping track of the same thing twice.  You want the selected `object` and the selected `id`.  If you keep track of the selected `object` you always have the id as well.  I would suggest you try to keep track of just the selected object.  When you need the id just use `object.id`

Why  dont you select the object and then sync the property:

```
<select name="currentlySelected" ng-model="selectedItem" 
        ng-options="cat as cat.name for cat in selectOptions"
        ng-change="change()">
</select>
```

Then in your code

```
$scope.change = change;

function change() {
   $scope.selectedId = $scope.selectedItem && $scope.selectedItem.id
}
```

Comment: you're right about keeping track twice. thanks. I don't understand, however, where selectedId is coming from

Comment: Please explain?  I renamed `selectedId` to selectedItem` because I didn't want it named incorrectly.  In the change listener above you can set the `$scope.selectedId = parent.id`.

Comment: in your html you set the ng-change directive to `change(selectedId)` . What is this `selectedId` variable?

Comment: I still don't understand but I will accept your answer since you mention how I am keeping track of things unnecessarily.

Comment: @user3494047 thats just a typo i copied yours from above.  I just updated the example and removed it because you can just reference selectedItem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object as the value reference:

```
<select name="currentlySelected" ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="cat as cat.name for cat in selectOptions"> <!-- You don't need the ng-change, it's not neccecary -->
```

And in your controller, you need to save a the reference to the object in the array:

```
$scope.change = function ($arrayId) {
     $scope.currentlySelected = $scope.selectOptions[$arrayId];
     console.log($scope.selectedId);  // THE MODEL HOLES THE OBJECT ITSELF
 };
 $scope.change(1); // EXAMPLE for changing the value from the code
```

Comment: who is the `change` function called if you remove the ng-change directive?

Comment: @user3494047 this is just for changing the model from the controller, you have already binded `selectedId` in `ngModel` so angular does all the work for you when the user changes the value

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check the sample below, this should help you to get things done

`ng-options="{catId: cat.id, index: idx} as cat.name for (idx, cat) in selectOptions"`

```js
angular.module('app', []).run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.selectOptions = [{id: 1, name: 'name1'}, {id: 2, name: 'name2'}, {id: 3, name: 'name3'}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<select name="currentlySelected" ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="{catId: cat.id, index: idx} as cat.name for (idx, cat) in selectOptions">
</select>
  <p>
    selectedId: {{selectedId}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does answer my question exactly as I wanted, even though I agree that I am keeping track of things twice unnecessarily so there is a better solution. I didn't down vote, though

Comment: @user3494047glad it solves your problem, maybe mark as answer tho